# Build tool for both JavaScript and Python

Tags: javascript, python, build-automation

I'm about to create a web app written in python on the backend and javascript on the frontend. I'm looking for a tool like Ant that lets you run some tests(for both python and js) and if they pass then do the next task, like minify js files or generate documentation.

I've not decided the js test framework yet. It would be the one that best fits with the build tool. Probably one accessible from the command prompt.

I'm aware that nose lets you automate your tests, but I need to do it for both languages and then do the rest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a system such as [Buildout](http://www.buildout.org/) along with a look at [JS Minify In Buildout](http://blog.toms-projekte.de/?p=33) looks like that is the way to go.

I have used Buildout in-conjunction with [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) to perform my automated builds and deployments in the past.